# Merge Fasta and Qual files with different headers order in FASTQ

Tags: perl, sorting, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

I am trying to merge a fasta file and a qual file in a new fastq file having in mind the case that the two files might be provided with different order in their sequence IDs. To do that, I tried the first step of my script to be the sorting of the sequences which works perfectly when I test it as a separate script. The same with the rest, when I run separately the part where it combines the files in a fastq, it runs perfectly. But now that I am trying to combine the two methods in one script it doesn't work and I don't know what else to do! I would appreciate it if you can help me.

Here is my script as far. It creates the new fastq file but the content is messed up and not what I want. I run it from terminal like this:

```
$ perl script.pl reads.fasta reads.qual > reads.fq
```

Script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die ("Usage: script.pl reads.fasta reads.qual > reads.fq") unless  (scalar @ARGV) == 2;

open FASTA, $ARGV[0] or die "cannot open fasta: $!\n";
open QUAL, $ARGV[1] or die "cannot open qual: $!\n";

my $offset = 33; 
my $count = 0;
local($/) = "\n>";

my %id2seq = ();
my $id = '';
my %idq2seq = ();
my $idq = '';
my (@sort_q, @sort_f);

while(<FASTA>){
    chomp;
        if($_ =~ /^>(.+)/){
            $id = $1;
        }else{
            $id2seq{$id} .= $_;
        }
     }

for $id (sort keys %id2seq)
    {
     @sort_f = "$id\n$id2seq{$id}\n\n";
     print @sort_f;
    }

while(<QUAL>){
chomp;
    if($_ =~ /^>(.+)/){
        $idq = $1;
    }else{
        $idq2seq{$idq} .= $_;
    }
}

for $idq (sort keys %idq2seq)
    {
    @sort_q = "$idq\n$idq2seq{$idq}\n\n";
    print "@sort_q";
    }

while (my @sort_f) {
chomp @sort_f;
my ($fid, @seq) = split "\n", @sort_f;   
my $seq = join "", @seq; $seq =~ s/\s//g;
my $sortq = @sort_q;
chomp my @sortq;
my ($qid, @qual) = split "\n", @sortq;

@qual = split /\s+/, (join( " ", @qual));
# convert score to character code:
my @qual2 = map {chr($_+$offset)} @qual;
my $quals = join "", @qual2; `enter code here`
die "missmatch of fasta and qual: '$fid' ne '$qid'" if $fid ne $qid;
$fid =~ s/^\>//;
print STDOUT (join( "\n", "@".$fid, $seq, "+$fid", $quals), "\n");
$count++;
}
close FASTA;
close QUAL;
print STDERR "wrote $count entries\n";
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does "the content is messed up?" mean? What are you getting? What do you want to get? (Small) sample input, expected and actual output files should be included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I have used perl, but I would approach this using a hash of key/value pairs for both the fasta and quality input. Then write out all the pairs by looping over the fasta hash and pulling out the corresponding quality string.

I have written something in python that will do what you need, you can see it in action [here](https://repl.it/@alexomics/JubilantRobustTriangle):

It assumes that your input looks like this:
**reads.fasta**

```
>fa_0
GCAGCCTGGGACCCCTGTTGT
>fa_1
CCCACAAATCGCAGACACTGGTCGG
```

**reads.qual**

```
>fa_0
59 37 38 51 56 55 60 44 43 42 56 65 60 68 52 67 43 72 59 65 69
>fa_1
36 37 47 72 34 53 67 41 70 67 66 51 47 41 73 58 75 36 61 48 70 55 46 42 42
```

**output**

```
@fa_0
GCAGCCTGGGACCCCTGTTGT
+
;%&387<,+*8A<D4C+H;AE
@fa_1
CCCACAAATCGCAGACACTGGTCGG
+
$%/H"5C)FCB3/)I:K$=0F7.**
@fa_2
TCGTACAGCAGCCATTTTCATAACCGAACATGACTC
+
C?&93A@:?@F,2:'KF*20CC:I7F9J.,:E8&?F
```

---

```
import sys


# Check there are enough arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Usage: {s} reads.fasta reads.qual > reads.fq'.format(s=sys.argv[0]), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# Initalise dictionaries for reads and qualities
read_dict = dict()
qual_dict = dict()

fa_input = sys.argv[1]
qual_input = sys.argv[2]

# Read in fasta input
with open(fa_input, 'r') as fa:
    for line in fa:
      line = line.strip()
      if line[0] == '>':
        read_dict[line[1:]] = next(fa).strip()
      else:
        next(fa)

# Read in quality input
with open(qual_input, 'r') as qual:
    for line in qual:
      line = line.strip()
      if line[0] == '>':
        qual_dict[line[1:]] = next(qual).strip()
      else:
        next(qual)

count = 0
# Iterate over all fasta reads
for key, seq in read_dict.items():
    # Check if read header is in the qualities data
    if key in qual_dict.keys():
        # There's both sequence and quality data so write stdout
        read_str = '@{header}\n{seq}\n+\n{qual}'.format(
            header=key,
            seq=seq,
            qual=''.join([chr(int(x)) for x in qual_dict[key].split(' ')]))
        print(read_str, file=sys.stdout)
        count += 1
    else:  # not found
        # Write error to stderr
        print('Error: {k} not found in qual file'.format(k=key), file=sys.stderr)

# Print count to stderr
print('{c} reads written'.format(c=count), file=sys.stderr)
```

If you need to use an offset for the quality score edit
`qual=''.join([chr(int(x)) for x in qual_dict[key].split(' ')]))` to
`qual=''.join([chr(int(x) + offset) for x in qual_dict[key].split(' ')]))` and define an `offset` variable before this.